# XMS.Net 2.1.0.0/1 CWSMQ0282E

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

We're using XMS.Net to connect to a WebSphere MQ server V7; this has always worked fine with a V6 server but since the "other party" has upgraded to V7 we expierienced some trouble. Most of it has been fixed but now I've stumbled upon an error that I can't explain, nor find anything about:

```
CWSMQ0282E: A null value has been used for argument BUFFER = <> NULL within method ImportMQMDMesageBuffer(WmqSession, WmqDestination, MQMD,byte[],int,int).
The preceding method detected an invalid  null argument.
If necessary, recode the application to avoid the error condition.
Stacktrace:    at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.WmqReceiveMarshal.ImportMQMDMesageBuffer(MQMessageDescriptor mqmd, Byte[] buffer, Int32 dataStart, Int32 dataEnd)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.WmqAsyncConsumerShadow.Consumer(Phconn hconn, MQMessageDescriptor mqmd, MQGetMessageOptions mqgmo, Byte[] pBuffer, MQCBC mqcbc)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.UnmanagedNmqiMQ.NmqiConsumerMethodUM(Int32 hconn, IntPtr structMqmd, IntPtr structMqgmo, IntPtr buffer, IntPtr structMqcbc)
```

The only thing I *think* I know about the cause of this error is that we sent a message and I'm expecting the CoA and CoD messages; I'm expecting these to be in the queue and when I shut down my consumer listening for these messages the rest works fine.

I have absolutely no idea what is going on...

**EDIT**

This is the minimum testcase:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;
using IBM.XMS;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Setup unhandled exception "logging"
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

            //Change this to your own needs!
            string QueueManager = "CONTOSO";
            string Channel = "MYCOMPANY.CONTOSO.TCP";
            string Queue = "MYCOMPANY.REPORTQ";
            string HostIP = "192.168.1.29"
            int Port = 1416;

            //Create connection
            var factoryfactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
            var connectionfactory = factoryfactory.CreateConnectionFactory();

            connectionfactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QueueManager);
            connectionfactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HostIP);
            connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, Port);
            connectionfactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, Channel);
            connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_VERSION, XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_V2);
            connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED);

            var connection = connectionfactory.CreateConnection();
            connection.ExceptionListener = new ExceptionListener(OnXMSExceptionReceived);

            //Create session
            var session = connection.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.ClientAcknowledge);

            //Create consumer
            var queue = session.CreateQueue(string.Format("queue://{0}/{1}", QueueManager, Queue));
            queue.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_TARGET_CLIENT, XMSC.WMQ_TARGET_DEST_MQ);  //Prevent automatic RFH (or JMS) headers in messages...
            var consumer = session.CreateConsumer(queue);
            consumer.MessageListener = new MessageListener(OnMessageReceived);  //Messages received will be handled by OnMessageReceived

            //Start the connection (which starts the consumer to listen etc.)
            Console.WriteLine("Starting");
            connection.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Started; press any key to stop");

            //Now we wait...
            Console.ReadKey();

            //Tear down the connection
            Console.WriteLine("Stopping");
            connection.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped; press any key to end application");

            //Keep the console around
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void OnMessageReceived(IMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message received");
            if (message is IBytesMessage)
            {
                var bytesmsg = (IBytesMessage)message;
                var data = new byte[bytesmsg.BodyLength];
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
            }
            else
            {
                //The message is not an IBytesMessage, check to see if it is a Feedback-type message
                if (message.PropertyExists(XMSC.JMS_IBM_FEEDBACK))
                {
                    //Figure out which type of feedback message this is
                    int feedback = message.GetIntProperty(XMSC.JMS_IBM_FEEDBACK);
                    switch (feedback)
                    {
                        case MQC.MQFB_COA:
                            Console.WriteLine("COA received");
                            break;
                        case MQC.MQFB_COD:
                            Console.WriteLine("COD received");
                            break;
                        default:
                            //Unknown feedback type
                            Console.WriteLine("Unknown feedback");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //The message is not a feedback message; we don't know what this is so it's unexpected.
                    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected message received");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Acknowledging");
            message.Acknowledge();
            Console.WriteLine("Acknowledged");
        }

        private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            //Uh oh
            Console.WriteLine("*** UnhandledException ***");
            Console.WriteLine((e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message);
            Console.WriteLine("******************************");
        }

        private static void OnXMSExceptionReceived(Exception ex)
        {
            //Uh oh
            Console.WriteLine("*** OnXMSExceptionReceived ***");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("******************************");
        }
    }
}
```

Create a new (console)project, add a reference to IBM.XMS.dll (C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Tools\Lib\IBM.XMS.dll) and run the project. Put any message in the report queue and see what happens.

When connected to a V6 server everything is fine, V7 results in the exception being thrown.

Also we tried updating to 2.1.0.1 but to no avail...

**EDIT**

Here's what I'm seeing:
[image: Added a few more writelines but the crash is obvious]

[This is my trace log](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=P7q1x1ML) (Sorry, can't add it here since my message will be >30000 chars long) and [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=vuXRDDC9) is an even more detailed log (traceSpecification "all" instead of "debug").

I also tried switching the (test)application to .Net V2.0.50727.5456 but that doesn't help either.

**EDIT**

I seem to have narrowed it down to "empty" CoA's and CoD's; when messages are sent with the MQRO_COA_WITH_DATA or MQRO_COA_WITH_FULL_DATA (same for CoD) as opposed to MQRO_COA then the CWSMQ0282E error doesn't occur. So XMS.Net seems to crash on empty bodies for CoA's and CoD's. I need to confirm some things to ensure it's not caused by other stuff in my project interfering but I'm quite sure this is the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can determine this exception, indeed, occurs on "empty" CoA's en CoD's. When messages are sent with the `MQRO_COA_WITH_DATA` / `MQRO_COD_WITH_DATA` (or even bulkier `MQRO_COA_WITH_FULL_DATA` / `MQRO_COD_WITH_FULL_DATA`) the exception doesn't occur. We will file a "PMR" with IBM to confirm.

Comment: @roblll Can you please answer how this case ended up? We are getting the same error here.

Answer (score 0):

The exception appears to be because the received message does not have message body. If the message received is because of either MQRO_COD or MQRC_COA option (set when the original message was sent) would not have any message body. When XMS tries to process messages without any body, it's getting into trouble.

I am puzzled as to how this was working when using MQ v6. You may want to check if the application that's sending the original message has been changed off late.

Also for XMS to process any message, the incoming message must contain required JMS headers. MQRO_COD/MQRO_COA are automatically generated by the queue manager and will not contain JMS headers.

Few other suggestions on the code snippet above:

1) An instance of `IPEndpoint` is not really required. You can simply set hostname or IP address as a string and port number as integer.

2) `XMSC.RTT_BROKER_PING_INTERVAL` need not be set when connecting WMQ.

3) Since you have used`AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge`while creating a session, no need to call `message.Acknowledge()` in `OnMessageReceived`method.

Comment: 1) IPEndpoint is used because I lifted the code from a bigger project; will change for the test application but that won't change anything functional
2) Will remove, but that won't solve anything either I'm afraid
3) This was lifted incorrectly; it is actually ClientAcknowledge

I'll get back to the rest of your post.

Comment: It is working fine in V6; the OnMessageReceived checks what kind of message is being received (actual message or report (CoA/CoD)). I left out the implementation of the OnMessageReceived since it doesn't even get called; XMS.Net *SHOULD* call the function but it crashes befor it gets around to call it. The sending application hasn't been changed (since our own application is the sending party). I will update the code above to reflect your suggested changes and show a little more of the OnMessageReceived implementation (even though it doesn't matter since it doesn't get called).

Comment: I have updated the example/test code. In any case, whatever the bug might be, do you agree that **at least** the "Message received" line should be written to the console? What I'm seeing is "...blablablah Started, press any key..." and then **BOOM** (since there are CoA's/CoD's on the queue). When I remove the CoA/CoD messages manually the application starts fine. Putting a "test message" on the queue with MQ Explorer is handled fine ("Message received" and then the rest of the implementation). And again: this used to work fine in V6.

Comment: For XMS to deliver a message to application, the message must contain certain headers. If they are not present, the message would be routed to DLQ or a BOQ. In your case the CoA/CoD messages don't have a body or any header. So the message should have gone to a dead letter queue or a back out queue if one is defined. There could be a bug here. Currently your application uses XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED for connection mode. You could try changing the connection mode to XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_MANAGED and see how it goes. It would be good to open a PMR with IBM to get a definite answer.

Comment: I am using the WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED because of [this](http://riii.nl/gqes3). Also, there is no WMQ_CM_CLIENT_MANAGED [as far as I can see](http://riii.nl/97tuu) or find [at IBM](http://riii.nl/cen5p). Commenting out the line (e.g. using the default setting) results in "CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during the call to the method ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiException: Exception of type 'IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiException' was thrown. Blahblah Reasoncode 2538" (Host not available???). I can't open a PMR with IBM as I am only a client "endpoint/enduser".

Comment: Sorry my mistake. It is just XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT.

Comment: In any case, whether it is CLIENT or CLIENT_UNMANAGED, the issue is with receiving CoA/CoD messages. I think you need to contact IBM via PMR.

Comment: The party using the MQ server is going to open a PMR with IBM. Meanwhile, I have added another [logfile](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=vuXRDDC9). As far as I understand, at 14:38:57.673750 the consumer is started and running. _Just_ before 14:38:57.705000 XMS.net detects a message (which is either a CoA or CoD, both have the same effect) on the queue and starts to process it. And then it all blows up. XMS.Net never gets around to calling "my code"; it crashes internally. Again; this **does** work with a V6 MQ server, V7 blows up. It is, unfortunately, hard for me to determine any differences.

Comment: @Shashi Can you please elaborate on this topic because we are receiving the same error which causes crashes on the client application?