# Buffer is null in ImportMQMDMesageBuffer, causes client application to crash

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

We are facing a difficult problem, I hope someone can give advice on how we can troubleshoot this.

We encounter following XMSException in our logging:

```
IBM.XMS.XMSException: CWSMQ0282E: A null value has been used for argument BUFFER = <> NULL within method ImportMQMDMesageBuffer(WmqSession, WmqDestination, MQMD,byte[],int,int). 
The preceding method detected an invalid  null argument. 
If necessary, recode the application to avoid the error condition. 
   at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.WmqReceiveMarshal.ImportMQMDMesageBuffer(MQMessageDescriptor mqmd, Byte[] buffer, Int32 dataStart, Int32 dataEnd) 
   at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.WmqAsyncConsumerShadow.Consumer(Phconn hconn, MQMessageDescriptor mqmd, MQGetMessageOptions mqgmo, Byte[] pBuffer, MQCBC mqcbc) 
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.UnmanagedNmqiMQ.NmqiConsumerMethodUM(Int32 hconn, IntPtr structMqmd, IntPtr structMqgmo, IntPtr buffer, IntPtr structMqcbc)
```

After this XMSException, the Windows Service crashes. The difficult part is that we can't reproduce this behavior on our dev environment. We are still troubleshooting, we couldn't find what's the root cause of this issue.

Below you can find information on how we make connection:

Used version: IBM.XMS 8.0.0.5

A connection is created this way:

```
XMSFactoryFactory factory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ); 
IConnectionFactory cf = factory.CreateConnectionFactory(); 
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED); 
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostname); 
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, port); 
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, channelname); 
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, qmname); 
IConnection connection = cf.CreateConnection();
```

Session is created this way:

```
ISession session = connection.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
```

Destination is created this way:

```
destination = session.CreateQueue("queuename"); 
destination.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY, XMSC.WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY_MQ); 
destination.SetBooleanProperty(XMSC.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, true); 
destination.SetBooleanProperty(XMSC.WMQ_MQMD_READ_ENABLED, true);
```

Listener is created this way:

```
IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination); 
consumer.MessageListener = listenerDelegate;
```

The same `XMSException` is also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012046/xms-net-2-1-0-0-1-cwsmq0282e) a few years ago. I see they have opened a PMR for this issue, but without any update...

Comment: Does the your `listenerDelegate` receive a notification of a message before the failure?

If so then please share the first 5-10 lines of your `listenerDelegate` code. This is where your application will be receiving a message and where the buffer will have become NULL.

If not then there is something about the message, perhaps its routing, that is causing the null buffer. Are you able to use the admin console to see what is peculiar about the message that your app should be receiving?

Comment: @chughts No, the exception occurs internally in one of the IBM libraries. It's happening earlier in the code.

Comment: @subbaraoc sending and receiving messages is not a problem. The difficult part is, this happens on a specific message I suppose. But I don't know which message is causing this.

Comment: This isnt simply that a message with a zero length payload is put on the queue and being consumed?

Comment: Did you check the DeadLetterQueue? The message could have been treated as poison message

Comment: @JasonE it's possible yes, but shouldn't IBM handle this message without throwing a nullreference which causes a crash?

Comment: @Ozkan Well its throwing an XMS exception rather than a nullref, and the exception is because the code explicitly checks there is a payload to consume (I think its because it expects an rfh header on the buffer, so it should be invalid not to have one at a guess)

Comment: @JasonE to be precise, in the method `NmqiConsumerMethodUM`, this check is done: `buffer != IntPtr.Zero && mqcbc.DataLength != 0` if this is `true`, then it passes the buffer to `Consumer`, because one of the parts in the condition is `false`, buffer stays `null`

See stack trace for method locations.

Comment: @JasonE, JMS can process messages without a RFH header (MQ type messages), are you saying that XMS can not?  Ozkan, can you reproduce it by putting a empty message on the queue?  You can reproduce a empty message by creating a file with three lines: line 1: `* DMPMQMSG`, line 2: `N`, line 3: `X`.  To put the message to the queue use the command `dmpmqmsg -m QMGRNAME -o QUEUENAME -f FILENAME -Cd`

Comment: @JoshMc yes! I just got the same error here locally. The empty message caused the same error. So how can this be fixed? What do you expect `IBM.XMS` to do with such an empty message? Or in other words, how can I make the client application not crash if this is happening? I assume `IBM.XMS` should handle such empty messages on another way instead of throwing an XMSException which leads to a crash?

Comment: Ozkan, I would suggest first that you attempt to reproduce with the latest dll 8.0.0.11.  I don't work for IBM, but I would expect the API not to crash on a empty message, it should at least try to handle it as a poison message and attempt to put it to a backout queue if configured on the queue you are reading from or to the DLQ, this would be the behavior I would expect JMS to have.  You may want to ask your client why they are putting messages with a empty payload to the queue as well.

Comment: Can you try a message with not RFH header but that does have some data?  Just change the line 3 to `S "TEST MESSAGE"`.  That would not have  RFH header, I think based on the inf you put above about what `NmqiConsumerMethodUM` checks that it would not crash.

Comment: @JoshMc okay, but that's not the point. The point is, IBM should not crash in such case. What can I change in the code so my client application doesn't crash? I'll try a test message with data anyway, I'll write here what it does.

Comment: Ozkan, I know it is not the point but the comment above from @JasonE said he thought it was "because it expects an rfh header on the buffer".  I think based on what you stated it is simply because the message is null not because there is not a RFH header.  In either case I agree it shouldn't error out with no possible way for you to handle it.

Comment: Just to be clear, my comment about expecting rfh was a guess, I was looking at the code and the variables used within that function. I agree you should be able to process empty messages, I was trying to answer the question "we couldn't find what's the root cause of this issue". At this point it would be a question via PMR to IBM saying you cannot consume empty messages. However a workaround for you obviously is to avoid putting empty messages on the queue

Comment: @JoshMc If I put some data in the 3rd line like you said `S "TEST MESSAGE"`, then it can process succesfully. It only crashes if `X ` is put there. This leads to a crash also: `S ""`

Comment: Tested all possible cases on third line, these lead to a crash: `X `, `X`, `S `, `S`, `S ""`

Comment: So is this empty message problem specific to XMS, and does not apply to JMS or MQI ?

Comment: @chughts I know it does not impact MQI, I tested GETing a null message yesterday and it was fine.  Ozkan, you said you are only a client to a MQ server at another company so you can not open a PMR.  Wonder if you could report this via the hacker one site as a denial of service issue as all you need to do to take down a XMS async listener is send it a message with a null body.  IBM will take security issue reports via that site.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll definitely submit this.

Comment: Ozkan, I noticed this APAR released yesterday, apparently JMS also had a similar issue, only in that case it did not crash the message listener, it only logged an error and did not deliver the message.  See [IT27995: The MQ classes for JMS do not invoke a message-driven bean (MDB)application if the message body is zero bytes](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT27995).

Comment: @JoshMc Great! Thanks for the URL.

Comment: @JoshMc the error they are showing on that page is different from what I encounter. I hope XMS is covered also.

Comment: I don't think XMS is covered or it would mention it.  Did you have and success with hackerone?

Comment: Didn't have the time to submit sadly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On March 28th 2019 IBM released an APAR that appears to be an exact match for the issue you reported.

[IT28062: While getting an empty message, XMS .Net applications reports CWSMQ0282E and crash.](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT28062)

Unfortunately the APAR is not included in any current releases of MQ (*As of March 29th*).  You will need to either wait for a release to come out which includes this APAR or get your client to open a PMR and ask them for a IFIX for this APAR against the version of MQ you are using.

The APAR is targeted for the following maintenance levels, I also added the target date for each level from [IBM MQ planned maintenance release dates](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg27006309).

```
Version    Maintenance Level   Planned Release Date
v8.0       8.0.0.12            2Q 2019
v9.0 LTS   9.0.0.7             2Q 2019
v9.1 LTS   9.1.0.3             Not noted yet, 9.1.0.2 is targeted for 2Q 2019
v9.1 CD    9.1.3               CD releases historically have been between
                               2 and 6 months apart.
                               9.1.2 was released March 21 2019.
```

Comment: So if we install version `8.0.0.12` the fix will be included?

Comment: @Ozkan 8.0.0.12 was recently released and should include this fix.